# How to create company and branch relationship using Mongoose framework(Mongodb)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, mongoose

I have a collection in mongo which has all the details for companies.

```
var companyModel = mongoose.model('company', new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  address: {type: String},
  state: {type: String},
  city: {type: String},
  phoneNo: {type: Number},
  childsNo: {type: Number},
  poc: {type: Number},
  subscribtion: {type: Number}
}, {versionKey: false}));
```

from the above data, there are individual companies as well as company branches. Companies and branches have same details, So I want to maintain a single collection but want to differentiate the difference between a company and branch. I have only one level of branch.

After I design a collection, I should be able to find which company have which branch, If there are no branches it should say there are no branches.

Please let know the best design for this?

Answer (score 0):

A one to many relationship from Companies to Branches. Let branches have a reference to their parent company as well.

```
var companyModel = mongoose.model('company', new Schema({
 ...
 branches : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'branch'}]
 ...
});
var branchModel = mongoose.model('branch', new Schema({
 ...
 parent : { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'company' }
 ...
});
```

The rest is just proper use of the `$in` operator, which you can find [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html).

Comment: I don't want to create two models. In One model I want to add one more field like parent company id and want to refer to it. Looking for the best way to do everything in one model?

Comment: Then just move the parent field from the branch into the company model. You'll want to do checks to make sure the parent field is explicitly undefined if you're saving a parent itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply defining the `branch` schema withing the `company` schema. However a more cleaner way is to define the `branch` schema separately, but have it nested within the `company` schema. Below are both implementations:

First implementation:

```
var companyModel = mongoose.model('company', new Schema({
  ...
  branches: [{name: String}]
  ..
});
```

Second implementation (much cleaner in my opinion):

```
var Branch = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});
var companyModel = mongoose.model('company', new Schema({
  ...
  branches: [Branch]
  ...
});
```

Either way, you still have your array of `branches` within the `company` model.